Does loading items in parallel with different load times cause biased sampling?
This is for sampling images for ML training. If there are multiple threads loading data, but each item can take a different time due to different resolutions or disk speeds. The loaded images will get consumed in the order they're loaded, not in the order they were sampled. Could this cause the output distribution to not match the requested, input distribution? For now, let's only consider uniform random.
It does seem biased during startup. Let's say there's only 2 items, heads and tails and heads takes 1000s to load and tails only 1s. Then at the beginning (for the 1st N items, where N is # threads), you would get almost all tails.
But then in the long run, it seems unbiased. I made a simulation to test it. But that only checks whether every bin was sampled the same # times. Truly random sequences also have other properties like every sub sequence also being equally likely. Maybe there are
other randomness properties that aren't being satisfied.
Would really appreciate an intuitive explanation why it's biased or not
